How do I generate cardano wallet offline
quick question. for the wallet generation with address and private keys.
can we do it without setting up our node or using any public node, just by using algorithms or any client library? in any language?

Lucid has a nice example and instruction:
https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/how-do-i-generate-cardano-wallet-offline

Hi Kayvan, the link you added is redirecting to same page, I think you've mistakenly provided wrong link, can you please share the correct link again, thanks

oops, my bad, Here is the link for wallet selection/generation:
https://lucid.spacebudz.io/docs/getting-started/choose-wallet/
